# Panning, zooming, and dragging in a C#/XAML control?

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, controls, zooming, panning

Is there a XAML control which would allow me to add a few Images, and then allow the user to pan, zoom, and drag those images? I'm creating a Windows 8 app which needs to have images (cards) on a background, and the user should be able to pan around, zoom in, and drag the cards. I'm fine using a third-party solution (as long as it's not paid) if there's no built-in way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the ManipulationDelta events. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465387.aspx) for some examples of how to work with it.

XAML Example

```
<Rectangle Name="TestRectangle" Width="200" Height="200" Fill="Blue" ManipulationMode="All"/>
```